# Register asset in Shopify via script tag API

Tags: api, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing an application that of now adds two assets to store's theme via Assets API: template.html and script.js.
script.js is loading template.html from public_url that is available to me when I add template asset. After that I take public url of script.js and add it via script_tag API to the theme.

The purpose of template.html is to allow the store's owner to change appearance of what script is generating. 
So my concern and a question hereafter is that after owner changes the template the public url of  the template would change (correct me if I'm wrong) and there is no script_tag API that allows me to register js.liquid using {asset_url} and not the public url. How would I achieve the loading of a template.html asset (that can be edited by owner) to my js script and add it via scripttag?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I am running into the exact same scenario.

Comment: @developthewebz nope. Ended up modifying the theme. Question still holds

Comment: Thanks. I've posted everywhere (including the Shopify community forums and Slack channel), and no luck. I assume it's just not possible at this point. If I figure out a solution I'll report back here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use script tags in the situation you have mentioned. What you can do is import the `HTML` file into **theme.liquid** and not attach it via you js file. You can create a **Snippet** and import it in the following way:

```
{% include 'your-template.html' %}
```

By the above method, you do not need to worry about the public URL change once the file is updated.

Comment: But that's kind of defeats the "non-invasive" script tag approach and most importantly the safe app uninstall. I've been told that app should never change template files and it's considered a bad design, doesn't it?

Comment: I would disagree. You are just adding an include tag which won't fail even if the file is not present. Ideally you shouldn't change the theme file layout, indentation etc. I have followed many big Shopify apps and they do modify a lot of files. It should be okay if your changes don't break their original functionality.

Comment: But I won't be able to revert the theme back upon uninstall ( neither to remove template.html nor to change theme.liquid ). so owner will need to do the manual clean up which is what I'm trying to avoid. I am starting to think of creating own template editor in app admin section. Just don't see any other solution.

Comment: Creating a template editor is the best way to go. Solves all your issues.

Comment: Anyway thank you for responding. And Happy New Year!